# method overriding in var-arg methods

Tags: java

**Unexpected output in the case of method overriding - var-arg methods.
Parent class has method `m1(int...x)` and child class `m1(int[] x)`.**

1 -- `m1(int[] i)` in Child does it override `m1(int...x)` in Parent?

2 -- how come `p1.m1(3,10,9,0,5);` prints normal output and doesn't raise Complier or Runtime error that method call `p1.m1(3,10,9,0,5);` doesn't match with `m1(int[] i)` in class Child.

3 -- I have passed int values as an argument to `m1(int[] i)` in Child class but how is it able to save it to 1 dimensional int array i ??

```
class Parent {
    public void m1(int... x) {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void m1(int[] i) {
        System.out.println("child");
        System.out.println(i[0]);
        System.out.println(i.length);
    }

    public void m1() {
        System.out.println("child-0");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Parent p = new Parent();
        p.m1(10);

        Child c = new Child();
        c.m1();

        Parent p1 = new Child();
        p1.m1(3, 10, 9, 0, 5);

    }
}
```

Comment: The output of this program is --

parent
child-0
**child
3
5**

Answer (score 0):

The original version of your question asked this:

> First method call `p1.m1(3,10,9,0,5);` is it considered as method overriding or not?

Method *calls* don't override.  It is the method *declaration* that overrides, or not.

In fact, `m1(int[])` in `Child` does override `m1(int...)` in `Parent`!  See the end of my Answer for the JLS references that explain why.  The intuitive explanation is that varargs is syntactic sugar for an array argument that allows the *caller* to create an array implicitly.  The called method behaves the same in the regular case and the equivalent var args case.

So why does your code compile, run and give you the answer you are seeing?

It goes like this:

1. `p1` is declared as having type `Parent`.
2. The `Parent` class declares `public void m1(int... x)`
3. Therefore `p1.m1(3,10,9,0,5)` resolves to a method that allows varags.
4. Therefore, the code compiles to code that actually does this:

   ```
      p1.m1(new int[]{3,10,9,0,5})
   ```
5. At runtime, the value of `p1` is actually found to be an instance of `Child`.  Therefore, the method that is called is the `m1` override in the `Child` class.

---

> 1 -- m1(int[] i) in Child does it override m1(int...x) in Parent?

Yes.

> 2 -- how come p1.m1(3,10,9,0,5); prints normal output and doesn't raise Compiler or Runtime error that method call p1.m1(3,10,9,0,5); doesn't match with m1(int[] i) in class Child.

See explanation above.

But note that if you changed:

```
Parent p1 = new Child();
p1.m1(3,10,9,0,5);
```

to

```
Child p1 = new Child();
c1.m1(3,10,9,0,5);
```

you *would* get a compilation error.

> 3 -- I have passed int values as an argument to m1(int[] i) in Child class but how is it able to save it to 1 dimensional int array i ??

See explanation above.  The *caller* implicitly creates an `int[]` from the vargs parameters.

---

[JLS 8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1) states this:

> The declared type of a formal parameter depends on whether it is a variable arity parameter:
>
> - If the formal parameter is not a variable arity parameter, then the declared type is denoted by UnannType if no bracket pairs appear in UnannType and VariableDeclaratorId, and specified by §10.2 otherwise.
> - If the formal parameter is a variable arity parameter, then the declared type is an array type specified by §10.2.

[JLS 8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) states:

> An instance method mC declared in or inherited by class C, overrides from C another method mA declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>
> - ...
> - The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of mA.

and [JLS 8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) states:

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, **the same formal parameter types**.
>
> The signature of a method m1 is a subsignature of the signature of a method m2 if either:
>
> - m2 has the same signature as m1, or
> - the signature of m1 is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of m2.
>
>   Two method signatures m1 and m2 are override-equivalent iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1.